# How do I get PyCharm to show arbitrary text in the documentation of an instance attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, pycharm, python-sphinx, docstring

While PyCharm does support docstrings for functions and type hints, I cannot find a way to get extensive descriptions for what you could consider "public attributes" of class instances.

The best I can get is either comment or explicit type hinting to appear into the Documentation pane (`ctrl-q` by default), which is what I could get by introspection anyway: my aim is getting a description of what that variable means as opposed to what that variable is.

```
from typing import List
class Example:
   def __init__(self, name: str = 'default'):
       """This object is an example, but has some attributes.

       :param name: this name is kind of special because...
       :ivar some_attr: this attr contains phone numbers of friends!
       :ivar some_other_attr: this attr contains phone numbers of enemies!
       """
       self.name = name
       self.some_attr: List[int] = []
       self.some_other_attr: List[int] = []
```

I would expect PyCharm to tell me that I should not phone `self.some_attr` numbers at 3AM, and should really focus on those nasty numbers in `self.some_other_attr`. This should ideally happen in the documentation for `__init__`, but anywhere is better than nowhere.

I seem however to be ignored completely, and `ctrl-q` on `self.some_attr` just tells me `self.some_attr` is a `List[int]`, while `ctrl-q` on `__init__` just tells me I have a parameter `name`.